# Instagram api - redirect URI

Tags: api, instagram, instagram-api

I have registered `redirect_uri` as

```
http://localhost/auth.php
```

And I am requesting

```
http://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&response_type=code&scope=public_content&redirect_uri=http://localhost/auth.php? type=like&ltse=1
```

Then I received back this from Instagram:

```
localhost/auth.php?type=like&code=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

But I need two parameters (type and ltse) in the URI:
Like this:

```
localhost/auth.php?type=like&ltse=1&code=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

What is wrong in my request?

Answer (score 0):

Try using
http://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&response_type=code&scope=public_content**&type=like&ltse=1**&redirect_uri=http://localhost/auth.php

or you may pass the value in "state". The state is always returned with the code

Comment: I tried, no effect I have got this
http://localhost/auth.php?code=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

Your method this the state works fine, but I want to send my own parameters. 
http://localhost/auth.php?ltse=1&code= XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&state=somevalue

Comment: Here's an opinion. Encode "&type=like&ltse=1" and make the following request 
http://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&response_type=code&scope=public_content&STATE=ENCODED_VALUE&redirect_uri=http://localhost/auth.php